# What's the name for the type of x-axis scale used in frequency graphs?

Tags: audio, frequency, spectrum

I'm talking about the way the spacing between frequencies typically shrinks as the x-axis increases on frequency graphs. For example, in the graph below, the leftmost (labelled) x-axis interval represents only 20Hz (between 30 and 50), but the rightmost one represents 10,000Hz (between 10k and 20k).

[image]
<sub>(source: [centerpointaudio.com](http://www.centerpointaudio.com/Images/How-to-read-a-Frequency-Response-Graph-Diagram.png))</sub>

I'm 99% certain there's a word for this type of scale but I'm having a complete brain failure and I've forgotten what it could be...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's logarithmic.

Comment: It is a logarithmic scale, frequently used when representing frequency or decibels scales.

Answer (score 4):

It's a [Logarithmic scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale) & is used where a linear scale wouldn't really make sense & would reduce the detail in the lower portions of the graph.

As each octave doubles the frequency. The difference between, say, 50Hz & 100Hz is an octave, so is the difference between 5kHz & 10kHz.

If that information were to be presented on a linear scale, there would be so much space needed to represent the octave from 5-10k that the information for 50-100Hz would be lost way down the left hand side.

Comment: I would add that the logarithmic scale a more accurate representation of our perception of the frequency spectrum.